# High School Geometry - If $BC$ is the greatest side of $\triangle ABC$, $D$ & $E$ are points on $BC, CA$...

Tags: geometry, triangles

> If $BC$ is the greatest side of $\triangle ABC$, and $D$ & $E$ are points on $BC$ & $CA$, respectively, 
> prove that $BC \ge DE$.

Clearly, equality holds iff $D$ is on $B$ and $E$ is on $C$.

I have tried to prove the inequality comparing $\angle BAC$ and $\angle DEC$.

If $\angle DEC \ge \angle BAC,$ then $DC$ hence $BC$ is $\gt DE$.

Else, on similar grounds $DE\lt EC$ hence $\lt BC$.

Is there something I am missing out. And, most importantly, can someone suggest a more neat version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We assume as known that in any triangle $PQR$, the largest side is opposite the largest angle, and conversely.

**Lemma:** Let $PQR$ be a triangle, and let $X$ be in the interval $PR$, and not at an endpoint. Then $QX \lt QP$ or $QX \lt QR$ (or both). More compactly, $QX\lt \max(QP,QR)$.

**Proof:** Since angles $QXP$ and $QXR$ add up to $180^\circ$, one at least is $\ge 90^\circ$. So $\angle QXP$ is the largest angle in $\triangle QXP$, or $\angle QXR$ is the largest angle in $\triangle QXR$, or both. If $\angle QXP$ is the largest angle in $\triangle QXP$, then $QP \gt QX$. Similarly, if $\angle QXR$ is the largest angle in $\triangle QXR$, then $QR\gt QX$.

Now we look at our triangle $ABC$.  Suppose that $D=B$. If $E=C$, then $DE=BE=BC$. If $E\ne C$, then by the Lemma $BE$ (that is, $DE$) is $\lt\max(BC,BA)=BC$.

Suppose now that $D\ne B$. The case $E=C$ is easy.

If $B\ne D$ and $E\ne C$, draw the line $BE$. By the Lemma, we have $BE\lt BC$. Again by the Lemma, $DE\lt \max(BE,CE)\lt BC$. This completes the proof.

Comment: "The largest side is opposite the largest angle, and conversely." I call the broader principle the Three Bears Theorem: The Poppa-Bear side is opposite Poppa-Bear angle; the Momma-Bear side is opposite Momma-Bear angle; and the Baby-Bear side is opposite Baby-Bear angle. :)

Comment: Aren't we supposed to mention about the case when neither point is an endpoint ?

Comment: Of course, that's what the post does. That's taken care of by the last two sentences, I will separate them out so it will be more clear.

Comment: Yeah, got mixed up with names there.. Nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Here is the answer in picture hope it is right
It works for each case and for d lying on any vertice we can prove by exterior angle theorem easily

Comment: It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Brother i dont have knowledge of TeX, can you suggest some book to learn tex?

Comment: [This one](http://www.docs.is.ed.ac.uk/skills/documents/3722/3722-2014.pdf), for instance.

Comment: thank u brother :)

Answer (score -1):

I have a geometric solution:

By extending $ED$ and $AB$ will intersect at $F$, assuming they are not parallel. Thus in $D$ $\triangle AEF$ we observe $\angle FAE=\angle BAC<\angle DEC$, and since $\angle BAC$ is the greatest angle we have $DC>DE$.